# Can I change the location/name of PyCharmProjects?

Tags: pycharm

I am using PyCharm 3.0 on Ubuntu 12.04. It has automatically created a folder called `~/PyCharmProjects` for storing project folders. Is it possible to:

- change the location of this folder?
- change the name of this folder?

(I couldn't find any reference to changing it in the interface, on the JetBrains site, or in the settings files. Either it isn't possible or (I hope) I missed something.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set any location for your project(s). Either through the File/New Project... menu, or File/Open... if you already have projects somewhere.

When you don't have anything left in the `~/PyCharmProjects` you can delete it safely.

If you want to go into more details: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/project.html

Comment: The same goes for PyCharm 3.4.1 on Windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using PyCharm 4.5 Community and this version he "remembers" the location of the last project you created. It works like this: you create a project in "/ home / user / workspace / MyProject". The next time you create a project the PyCharm will suggest to create in "/ home / user / workspace / untitled", ie it resembles the way and always suggests the same, since you can not move to another location.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a new project acquires the same name as the directory in which it is initially rooted.

Based on personal experimentation and some (cursory) reading of the cited documentation, you can change the location of a project simply by moving its root directory somewhere else.

I saw no evidence that you can move or rename a project from within the IDE, although you can create a new project (in a different location) or delete an existing one.

To rename the project, it appears that you have to rename its root directory and change the entry in the .idea/.name file.

This was all the tinkering and tampering I had patience for, so if someone actually knows easier or better ways to *move* a project or *rename* it, please let us know.  Thanks!