# Where is PyCharm's projects directory located?

Tags: pycharm

I'm trying to find the directory where all projects are stored within PyCharm's settings, but it's not clear where it's located.

Answer (score 2):

Pycharm has a default project location (which *might* depend on the PyCharm version and/or OS). At least in some cases it's `~/PyCharmProjects`.

Note that this default location shows up just as a *suggestion* when a new project is created, but one can choose a different location.

It's also possible to change the default project location, see [Change the default location of Pycharm Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981116/change-the-default-location-of-pycharm-project)

Pycharm also support creating projects from code already existing in some directory, in which case the above-mentioned suggestion is not even made.

With these in mind, if you really want to find **all** PyCharm projects you'd need to do a search for the `.idea` directories in which PyCharm stores its per-project settings.

But note that several other JetBrains Idea-based products beside PyCharm use the same directory name for the same purpose, so, if you have other such products installed you'd need to take a closer look to see which of such projects are PyCharm projects. An explanation for what's in that directory can be found in [How to manage projects under Version Control Systems](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839) (applicable to all of their Idea-based products, not just PyCharm)

Answer (score 1):

It is here:

```
C:\Users\<user>\PycharmProjects
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access PyCharm's project directory from a Linux terminal, you can find it at:

```
/mnt/c/Users/<USER>/PycharmProjects
```

Or
Go to your START menu and search for 'PycharmProjects'. You'll find the location at:

```
C:\Users\<USER>\PycharmProjects
```