# Change Pycharm default directory / folder

Tags: pycharm

I've just installed Pycharm Community edition in my Windows PC.
I want to change the default directory for my projects.

Now it is `C:\users\myuser\Pycharmprojects\untitled`

I want it to be `E:\PycharmProjects\my project name`

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the default location of Pycharm Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981116/change-the-default-location-of-pycharm-project)

Answer (score 2):

this issue is a duplicate of 
[Can I change the location/name of PyCharmProjects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262582/can-i-change-the-location-name-of-pycharmprojects)

But the answer not mentioned there is:

1. Make sure PyCharm is closed
2. Navigate to the C:\Users\MyName.PyCharm50\config\options\recentProjectDirectories.xml
   (note: read this page to figure out where these settings are on the different OS's: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/project-and-ide-settings.html)
3. Modify

   ```
   <option name="lastProjectLocation" value="D:\Dropbox\Learning\FullStack\Python" />
   ```

   and set the value=*whatever your desired folder is*.
4. Save the file, then open PyCharm.

(via http://makguidetosoft.blogspot.com/2016/01/pycharm-change-default-project-folder.html)